# Angular 6 mock REST api with Pact.js, Error : Failed: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular6, pact

I'm trying to mock an Angular Rest API by **Pact.js**, but getting error `Failed: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.`

My original API gets called instead of the mocked server.
When I try to GET http://localhost:1234/users (the mocked pact server api.)

I get result : `{"message":"No interaction found for GET /","interaction_diffs":[]}`

**Expected behaviour:** the actual Rest API call get diverted to mock server and I should get the mocked output. (see expectedUser in below code.), not the actual api result.

Below is my code:

**Karma.conf.js**

```
   ...
    pact: [{
      cors: true,
      port: 1234,
      consumer: "ui",
      provider: "usersservice",
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      dir: "pacts/",
      spec: 2
    }],
    proxies: {
       // below is a fake rest API I'm trying to mock.
      'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users': 'http://localhost:1234/users'
    },
...
```

**user.service.pact.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UsersService } from './shared/users.service';
import { User } from './shared/user';
import { PactWeb, Matchers } from '@pact-foundation/pact-web';

describe('UsersService pack test', () => {
    let provider;

    beforeAll(function (done) {
        provider = new PactWeb({
            cors: true,
            consumer: 'ui',
            provider: 'users-service',
            port: 1234,
            host: '127.0.0.1',
        });
        // required for slower CI environments
        setTimeout(done, 2000);

        // Required if run with `singleRun: false`
        provider.removeInteractions();
    });

    afterAll(function (done) {
        provider.finalize()
            .then(function () {
                done();
            }, function (err) {
                done.fail(err);
            });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule
            ],
            providers: [
                UsersService
            ],
        });
    });

    afterEach((done) => {
        provider.verify().then(done, e => done.fail(e));
    });

    describe('getUsers()', () => {
        const expectedUser: User[] = [{
            "id": 9,
            "name": "test user",
            "email": "test@user.xyz",
            "phone": "1-999-999-9999 x99999",
            }];

        beforeAll((done) => {
            provider.addInteraction({
                state: `provider return a expected user array`,
                uponReceiving: 'a request to GET a person',
                withRequest: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    path: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
                },
                willRespondWith: {
                    status: 200,
                    body: expectedUser, // to respond with defined data.
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            }).then(done, error => done.fail(error));
        });

        it('should get Person array', (done) => {

            const usersService: UsersService = TestBed.get(UsersService);
            usersService.getUsers().subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response) // this logs actual API response not mocked.
                expect(response).toEqual(expectedUser); // this fails
                done();
            }, error => {
                done.fail(error);
            });
        });

    });
 });
```

I followed below sources, but just not able to create and redirect to mocked API

https://reflectoring.io/consumer-driven-contracts-with-angular-and-pact/

https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/tree/master/pact/pact-angular

Comment: Please post the whole content of user.service.pact.spec.ts

Comment: FabricioLemos: I've added the full code of `user.service.pact.spec.ts`

Comment: @anoop Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean, nowhere in your test setup do you tell your code that it's API endpoint is different - you'll need to tell the http library/client to hit the pact API and not your real one (Pact doesn't automatically hijack your http client).

Also, your `WithRequest` looks to have an illegal path in it. You can't override the hostname in pact contracts.

Comment: I use proxy in `karma.conf.js` to tell the pact to use proxy api instead, also I used absolute path in `withrequest` as my API domain is different from angular host domain. For example: my frontend is hosted on `localhost:4200` and backend api is hosted on `localhost:3000`, Let me know if I miss something?

Comment: You've got it backwards. Pact is the mock server and you need to point your test code at the mock server so it can record the interactions. Pact has to run on localhost